# Adapt AR video to background

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a video that starts playing when him first frame is detected on AR scene. It seems that the picture comes to life. Video and picture are drawn in same colors.
How to dynamically adapt video to scene with different lighting?

[What I have now – color of video is very different from background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ipG0.jpg)
[What I want to achieve. Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oho0l.jpg)
[What I want to achieve. Example 2 in another lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW1do.jpg)
.
I use SceneKit
I added SKVideoNode on SKScene
I wrote my code in method

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ARKit 2 you can use the `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`'s `environmentTexturing` property to add realistic lighting to your scene. You can set it to `.automatic` if you do not need it to be super specific or `.manual` if you want full control over the environment textures

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_realistic_reflections_to_an_ar_experience 
This Page explains environment texturing a little bit better

For the `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` you can add a light to the video scene and update its lighting using the properties from an `ARLightingEstimate`. Get the `ARLightingEstimate` from either the `curentFrame` property of `ARSession` or by setting your view controller to the delegate and using the `session didUpdate frame` method

Comment: With `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` you can get a basic light estimate using the `lightEstimate` property of `ARFrame`